# Codeigniter's form_dropdown to display category name in dropdown list but insert category id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to display a dropdown for category list in my blog module in CI.

In Blog table:
 I have `news_id, category_id, news_title, news_slug`

In category table:
I have `category id, category name, category slug`

Update: Remember the form should insert cat id in blog table but display category name from another table
[here is one with more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316093/codeigniter-form-with-dropdown-select-with-categoryname-insert-to-categoryid-in)

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">News category <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('category_id'); ?>
        <?php $options = array( '' => 'Select category',

         foreach ($categories as $category) {
             # code...
         }
         ); 
         ?>

        <?php $htmlelements = 'class = "form-control" id="subject" required="required"';
        echo form_dropdown('', $options, set_value('category_id'), $htmlelements);
```

blog controller

```
function add()
    {       
        $this->load->library('form_validation');    
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('news_title', 'Blog Title', 'required|trim|xss_clean');           
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('news_body', 'news body', 'required|trim|xss_clean');         

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('category_id', 'Blog category', 'required|trim|xss_clean');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error">', '</span>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) // validation hasn't been passed
        {


            //$this->load->view('add_blog_view');
            $data['view_file'] = "add_blog_view";
            $this->load->module('template');
            $this->template->public_one_col($data);


        }
        else // passed validation proceed to post success logic
        {
            // build array for the model

            $form_data = array(
//$news_slug = ($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);
                            'news_title' => set_value('news_title'),
                            'news_slug' => set_value('news_slug'),
                            'news_body' => set_value('news_body'),
                            'category_id' => set_value('category_id')
                            //'news_slug' => set_value('news_slug')


                        );


            // run insert model to write data to db

            if ($this->mdl_blogs->SaveForm($form_data) == TRUE) // the information has therefore been successfully saved in the db
            {
                redirect('blogs/success');   // or whatever logic needs to occur
            }
            else
            {
            echo 'An error occurred saving your information. Please try again later';
            // Or whatever error handling is necessary
            }

        }

    }
```

full code add blog view

```
<?php // Change the css classes to suit your needs    

$attributes = array('class' => '', 'id' => '');
echo form_open_multipart('blogs/add', $attributes); ?>
<h1>Add a blog </h1>
<div class="form-group">

        <label for="news_title">News Title <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('news_title'); ?>

        <?php echo form_input( array( 'name' => 'news_title', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' =>'news_title', 'required' => 'required','placeholder' => 'Enter a title','rows' => '5', 'cols' => '80', 'value' => set_value('news_title') ) );?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">

        <label for="news_slug">News Slug <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('news_slug'); ?>

        <?php echo form_input( array( 'name' => 'news_slug', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' =>'news_slug', 'required' => 'required','placeholder' => 'Separate each word by underscore','rows' => '5', 'cols' => '80', 'value' => set_value('news_slug') ) );?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="news_body">News <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <?php echo form_error('news_body'); ?>


    <?php echo form_textarea( array( 'name' => 'news_body', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' =>'newsbody','rows' => '5', 'cols' => '80','placeholder' => 'Write here an article for blog', 'value' => set_value('news_body') ) )?>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">News category <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('category'); ?>

<?php 

$options = array( '' => 'Select category');
foreach ($categories as $catID => $category) {
    $options[$catID] =  $category;                
}

?>

        <?php $htmlelements = 'class = "form-control" id="subject" required="required"';
        echo form_dropdown('news_id', $options, set_value('category_id'), $htmlelements);


       // form_dropdown('category_id', $drop_category_id,$category_id);



        ?>


</div>                                            



        <?php echo "<br/>" . 

          form_submit(array('name' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'btnSubmit'), 'Submit'); ?>


<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

category view

```
<div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Category ID</th>
                        <th class="col-md-6">Category</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Category Slug</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Edit</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <?php

                    echo anchor('category/add', '<h2>Add Category</h2>');
                    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {

                    $category_name = $row->category_name;
                    $category_id = $row->category_id;
                    $cat_slug = $row->cat_slug;

                    ?>
                        <td class="col-md-2"><?php echo "<p>".$category_id. "</p>";?></td>
                        <td class="col-md-6"><?php echo "<p>".$category_name. "</p>";?></td>
                        <td class="col-md-2"><?php echo $cat_slug;?></td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">Edit</td>

                        </tr>


                    <?php



                        }



                    ?>

                </tbody>

              </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: You cannot throw a foreach within an array declaration like that.

Comment: hello xd6. how should i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<?php $options = array( '' => 'Select category',

         foreach ($categories as $category) {
                         # code...
              }
               ); 
           ?>
```

Try like this

```
$options['']="Select category";

foreach($categories as $category)
{
  $options[$category->id]=$category->categoryname // your code
}
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: and another error   A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: categories

Comment: Check whether $categories contains value or not and how you are passing categories. Share the controller code also.

Comment: please see my controller

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can do..

```
<?php

$options = array( '' => 'Select category');
foreach ($categories as $catID => $category) {
    $options[$catID] =  $category;                
}

?>
```

to pass variables from controller to view you need to the following:

```
$data['categories'] = $categories;  //you need to assign the categories array here
$this->load->view('add_blog_view', $data); //then pass this to the view
```

for more info, please check this [link](http://www.phpcmsframework.com/2013/07/passing-parameters-between-controller.html)

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: categories

Filename: views/add_blog_view.php

Line Number: 34

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @Robin, can you do var_dump($categories) and tell me what you got? and also include what is on the line 30-40, where the error is.

Comment: @Robin - Are you ensuring $data['categories'] is set in the controller that is loading this view? It is converted to $categories in the view.

Comment: hello Ugly Eddie  check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316093/codeigniter-form-with-dropdown-select-with-categoryname-insert-to-categoryid-in for those lines

Comment: controller is added above

Comment: @xd6_ var_dump returned null.

Comment: @Robin - you're missing the line in your controller where you would set $data['categories'] - typically you would call a method from a model to get DB data to place in $data['categories'], maybe similar to  $this->categories->get_categories() (if the model is Categories_Model)

Comment: @xd6_ can you provide me an example?

Comment: @Robin, example provided above. Please check.